# Python custom 404 response error

Tags: python

I wrote a hiscore checker for a game that I play, basically you enter a list of usernames into the .txt file & it outputs the results in found.txt.

However if the page responds a 404 it throws an error instead of returning output as " 0 " & continuing with the list.

Example of script,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2

def get_total(username):
 try:
  req = urllib2.Request('http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/index_lite.ws?player=' + username)
  res = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
  parts = res.split(',')
  return parts[1]
 except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
  if e.code == 404:
   return "0"
 except:
  return "err"

filename = "check.txt"

accs = []
handler = open(filename)
for entry in handler.read().split('\n'):
 if "No Displayname" not in entry:
  accs.append(entry)
handler.close()

for account in accs:
 display_name = account.split(':')[len(account.split(':')) - 1]
 total = get_total(display_name)
 if "err" not in total:
  rStr = account + ' - ' + total
  handler = open('tried.txt', 'a')
  handler.write(rStr + '\n')
  handler.close()
  if total != "0" and total != "49":
   handler = open('found.txt', 'a')
   handler.write(rStr + '\n')
   handler.close()
  print rStr
 else:
  print "Error searching"
  accs.append(account)

print "Done"
```

HTTPERROR exception that doesn't seem to be working,

```
 except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
  if e.code == 404:
   return "0"
 except:
  return "err"
```

Error response shown below.

[image: Python Error]

Now I understand the error shown doesn't seem to be related to a response of 404, however this only occurs with users that return a 404 response from the request, any other request works fine. So I can assume the issue is within the 404 response exception.

I believe the issue may lay in the fact that the 404 is a custom page which you get redirected too?

so the original page is " example.com/index.php " but the 404 is " example.com/error.php "?

Not sure how to fix.

For testing purposes, format to use is,

ID:USER:DISPLAY

which is placed into check.txt

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `total` can end up being `None`. In that case you can't check that it has `'err'` in it. To fix the crash, try changing that line to:

```
if total is not None and "err" not in total:
```

To be more specific, `get_total` is returning `None`, which means that either

- `parts[1]` is `None` *or*
- `except urllib2.HTTPError, e:` is executed *but* `e.code` is not 404.

In the latter case `None` is returned as the exception is caught but you're only dealing with the very specific 404 case and ignoring other cases.